# Monster Widget Plugin shown Notices

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

Hello Everything is working fine without Monster Widgets Plugin. But When i Install Monster Widget Plugin and Place this as a widget to test WordPress All Widgets its shown notices.

```
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Archives
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Calendar
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Categories
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Pages
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Meta
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Recent_Comments
NOTICE: E:\VertrigoServ\www\wp\wp-includes\widgets.php:1039 - Undefined index: WP_Widget_Recent_Posts
```

And some more like this. 
Anybody know about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove all widgets from theme and add all widgets via Plugins and problem is solved.
If we register widgets in theme then Monster Widget Plugin create problem and showing notices like i have post above.